# break a for-loop after specific condition match in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA1J/16

Here I am trying to match placeholder[@md.mnem='angen'][placeholder.text='UL'] and identify it's preceding <codes.head ID="" md.mnem="hg*"> and store it into variable. and collection all hg* records after that match until i find hg* record with same or smaller(in my example it is hg2, and if i find hg2 or hg1 i have to break the loop)

I am able to select the hg* records after a specific match but unable to break after matching same hg* or smaller one.

can anyone please help me to solve this, the xml and xsl can find in the below link.
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eieFA1J/16

Comment: Please show any relevant code samples, cut to a minimum, but complete enough the demonstrate the problem, directly as formatted code samples in the question. It is not clear why you say you want to "break a for-loop", there is no instruction to "break" an `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Incidentally, XSLT 3 has `xsl:iterate` with `xsl:break`, so perhaps, if your algorithm really needs to walk a sequence of nodes until you find a certain record, that might be one way to solve it. But there might be more declarative, functional ways. We will be able to tell, hopefully, if you show minimal code sample and explain the relation between input and output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSLT 3 `xsl:iterate` instead of an `xsl:for-each` might help to implement the conventional loop and break algorithm:

```
    <xsl:iterate select="$hgset">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@md.mnem gt $hgValue">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:break/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:iterate>
```

But of course you can also use a recursive function or template to implement the same in XSLT 2 or perhaps just select the first item in your sequence that "breaks" the condition and select anything "before" it with the `<<` operator.

Another option is to use `<xsl:for-each-group select="$hgset" group-ending-with="*[@md.mnem le $hgValue]"><xsl:if test="position() = 1"><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each-group>`.